# Custom character filter in analyzer not working

Tags: regex, full-text-search, couchbase, bleve

i am using regexp character filter in couchbase for my analyzer. desirable result following

```
phuong 1 -> phuong_1
phuong  12 -> phuong_12
```

Configuration character filter in Couchbase Web Console following

```
Regular expression : ([a-z])\s+(\\d)
Replacement: $1_
```

- Result of above configuration is produce term [phuong,1, 12 ]
- Desirable result is [phuong_1 , phuong_12]
- I have aligned this code many times But it still not working correct
- Can you help me this problem ?

Comment: nobody find method ?

Comment: Do you need to match this exact pattern? because if it is just a matter of white spaces you could use Regular expression: \s+ and Replacement: _

Comment: oh no . my expression -> digital is followed by space and a word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couchbase's Full text search is implemented in golang. Here's a playground illustration of how your regular expression works ..

https://play.golang.org/p/Jray7DTYZam

As you can see in the illustration above, $1x is equivalent to ${1x}, not ${1}x. So your replacement needs to be updated to `${1}_`.

Now this said, we have a limitation that variables ($1, ${2} etc.) aren't supported at the moment. I've created an internal ticket to extend support for this.

Comment: thank you for  feedback my question . Based on your answer ,i think replacement should be ${1}_${2}

Comment: Although the results were correct, couchbase still did not produce the correct terms
such as phuong_1 , phuong_12 . I test in elasticsearch ,it's working but couchbase not Any problem with couchbase ?

Comment: Looks like you found an issue! Check out https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-38312 and https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve/pull/1351 :)